# Why this WPF TabControl Binding Interface Error?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is my code below, but why one(Test1View) doesn't work and another(Test2View) work?

I think about it for a long time, but have no idea about it. Can anyone have ideas? Which documents should I read?

1、MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TabControl Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}">
        <!-- this is the header template-->
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding DisplayIndex}" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding ContentObject.BackgroundImageSource}" Width="50"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentObject.ShowContent}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

2、MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        vm = new WindowVM();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
        vm.Init();
    }

    private WindowVM vm;       
}
```

3、ViewModel:

```
public class WindowVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<ITestView> TabCollection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ITestView>();

    public void Init()
    {
        List<ITestView> list = new List<ITestView>()
        {
            new Test1View(), // it doesn't work
            new Test2View(), // it work
        };

        TabCollection.Clear();
        foreach (ITestView test in list)
        {
            TabCollection.Add(test);
        }
    }
}
```

4、Interface:ITestView、IContentTest

```
public interface ITestView
{
    IContentTest ContentObject { get; set; }
    int DisplayIndex { get; set; }
}

public interface IContentTest
{
    string ShowContent { get; set; }
    ImageSource BackgroundImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

5、DataSource：Test1View, it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Test1View : UserControl,ITestView //Test1View is a UserControl,Test1View.xaml is only a block grid.
{
    public Test1View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public IContentTest ContentObject { get; set; } = new ContentTest1();

    public int DisplayIndex { get; set; } = 1;
}

public class ContentTest1 : IContentTest
{
    public ContentTest1()
    {
        ShowContent = "header111";
        BackgroundImageSource = Application.Current.FindResource("Image111") as ImageSource; // <ImageSource x:Key="Image111">aaa.png</ImageSource>
    }
    public string ShowContent { get; set; }
    public ImageSource BackgroundImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

6、DataSource：Test2View, it work! Why Test1View doesn't work, but Test2View work?

```
public class Test2View : ITestView
{
    public IContentTest ContentObject { get; set; } = new ContentTest2();
    public int DisplayIndex { get; set; } = 2;
}

public class ContentTest2 : IContentTest
{
    public ContentTest2()
    {
        ShowContent = "header222";
        BackgroundImageSource = Application.Current.FindResource("Image111") as ImageSource; //<ImageSource x:Key="Image111">aaa.jpg</ImageSource>
    }

    public string ShowContent { get; set; }
    public ImageSource BackgroundImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a binding error in the output window while debugging?

Comment: What "doesn't work" exactly?

Comment: The whole purpose of MVVM is separation of UI and business logic, so you shouldn't have a UI control within your ViewModel.

Comment: @thatguy I have no binding error hint in this project XAML Binding Failures Window.

Comment: @mm8 This project  wants to show image in TabControl header, "doesn't work" means the code can't binding images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Test1View you would probably have to do the Bindings directly in the view. But the `TabControl` would not be able to display that either because the template does not account for direct binding of another view.

This could be done with a `ContentControl` in the ItemTemplate.
Generally you cannot easily display two different types of content in a template, in your example this is a view (Test1View) and a viewModel (Test2View).